# Python3 Unittest: How to compare with MagicMocks Using Operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Easiest thing is to start with an example...

Example code to put under test:

```
type1_instance1 = f1()
type1_instance2 = f2()

compareResult = type1_instance1 < type1_intstance2

if compareResult:
    print(type1_instance1.generate_value())
```

Instance 1 and 2 are instances of some custom class.

When under test `f1` and `f2` are mocked to return MagicMocks. So that methods of the custom class can be called on those returned values.

When the compare code is executed I get the error

> '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'MagicMock'

What's the best way to enable MagicMocks to work with overloaded operators?

Here was my solution:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return mock.MagicMock

compareable_MagicMock_Instance = MagicMock()
setattr(compareable_MagicMock_Instance, '__lt__', __lt__)

f1.return_value = compareable_MagicMock_Instance
f2.return_value = another_compareable_MagicMock_Instance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the `return_value` attribute of the `__lt__` attribute of the `MagicMock` object instead, and use `patch` to make `f1` and `f2` return the customized `MagicMock` instance:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
def f1():
    pass
def f2():
    pass
compareable_MagicMock_Instance = MagicMock()
compareable_MagicMock_Instance.__lt__.return_value = True
with patch('__main__.f1', return_value=compareable_MagicMock_Instance), patch('__main__.f2', return_value=compareable_MagicMock_Instance):
    type1_instance1 = f1()
    type1_instance2 = f2()
    compareResult = type1_instance1 < type1_instance2
    if compareResult:
        print('type1_instance1 is less than type1_instance2')
```

This outputs:

```
type1_instance1 is less than type1_instance2
```

Comment: I was thinking of that too but I saw in the docs under supported methods that __lt__ etc. are supported. So why are they not comparable already? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magicmock-and-magic-method-support

Comment: By "supported" the doc only means that when you mock those magic methods the listed names would be recognized as callable methods rather than normal attributes. You would still have to mock specific magic methods if you want to use them, as the methods are not implemented by default (and they would not be useful even if implemented by default since their default returning values are likely not what you want).